# create wordlist to crack password

Tags: passwords, aircrack-ng

I am trying to make a wordlist to crack a password.
remember that the password is 12 digits long and is made up of Uppercase letters and numbers at random without any numbers or letters repeating twice, and that it starts with the letter "x".

How do i make a wordlist like that, I tried crunch but did not see an option to have each digit only once or something to start with the letter "x".

Comment: What tool are you using to create this wordlist? Tags are helpful, but it's better to include all relevant information in the body of the question itself. The EDIT button is useful for this.

Comment: You might also consider Rainbow tables as the source to crack an alphanumeric list for upper, lower case, and numbers.

Comment: Maths is not my strong point but by my calculations creating a password list may not be viable here - as the permutations - baring compression - would require about 1600 terrabytes of disk space.   The time to crack this password on a single computer would take years. The number of permutations  would be 36x35x34x33x32x31x30x29x28x27x26 - and you would need to add 2 extra bytes (for x and a delimiter) for storage.  The question you are asking shows you dont have the knowledge base or skill to succeed in cracking the password.

Comment: I believe Rainbow tables are for hash cracking, not dictionary generation

Comment: @John per https://www.tobtu.com/rtcalc.php the number of combinations makes rainbow tables not very viable (unless you are a government agency). Also, if I understand it, generating your own rainbow tables would only be viable if you are cracking multiple passwords.